# UIButton in UIStackView button click is not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, uistackview

In `UIViewController` I have subview of `UIView` inside that I have a `UIStackView` like the below hierarchy:

**UIView -> UIStackView -> UIView -> UIView -> UIButton**

The UI which I design is working perfect but the button click is not working. I have created a IBAction but the click event is not working. I have checked the form nothing is helped me. Is anything should I need to do additionally?

How can I enable the button click event?

My button click Action

```
 @IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Button Clicked")
    }
```

My sample UI

[image]

Comment: Can you post screenshot of your Storyboard?

Comment: Updated the screenshot please check

Comment: Where have you placed the Button?

Please attach Storyboard screenshot so that I can help you out

Comment: X mark is the button

Comment: Have attached the storyboard screenshot please check

Comment: 1. comment those corner Radius code for some time and run your code and check whether button is clickable or not? 
2. Check each View user interaction is enable or not.

Then let me know if you are still having the issue.

Comment: Thanks for you response, sure

Comment: No, its not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190297/discussion-between-amir-khan-and-vignesh).

Comment: Have removed the corner radius and checked the user interaction case as well but no luck

Comment: Could you please confirm that checkmark  "User Interaction Enabled"  is enabled for whole chain ```UIView -> UIStackView -> UIView -> UIView -> UIButton```. And also please check that you have a proper connections for IBAction between storyboard and code.

Comment: I have the same issue, i finaaly fixed by removing hstack.alignment = .center, i don't know why but it is causin the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please check following -**

1. User interaction of each superview.
2. IBAction for all buttons.

If you are still having issue then let me know. Happy coding

Comment: most of times its all like that and won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Action connected to it and class of the object, if not rewire the thing or remove and drag a new object. Also check the constraints.